# Require change of file for every commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to demand change of specific file in every commit? E.g. I have "version.txt" file in my repo, indicating the current version of code and I need to change it every time I commit new changes. Can I make something to remind me to change version file, if I forgot to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to do that or if that is possible, but I did a little research and found this link that might be useful: https://pre-commit.com/

you could potentially create hooks to run before a commit to ensure your code is free of certain bugs and I'm sure you could add a check for the version.txt file as well!

Anyone please feel free to edit my answer!